# Pair strings and count the times that appear in a column together

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I want to pair the stings in Authors column but only those who appear at least one time together in a row.
I have a big dataset. That's why I can't create all the possible pairs and iteratively to check every row of the dataset. That's why I want the pairs tha appear together at least ones(the pairs that have weigh higher than 0).
For example:

```
data = {'Year': [2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016],
        'Conference': ['CIKM','CIKM', 'CIKM', 'ICWSM', 'ICWSM', 'ICWSM', 'ICWSM'],
        'Authors': ['Dimitrios Rafailidis,Fabio Crestani','Tomasz Kusmierczyk,Kjetil Nørvåg','Simranjit Singh Sachar,Nicholas Diakopoulos', 'Nasser Alsaedi,Pete Burnap,Omer F. Rana', 'Fabio Crestani,Nicholas Diakopoulos,Dimitrios Rafailidis,Omer F. Rana', 'Tomasz Kusmierczyk,Simranjit Singh Sachar,Dimitrios Rafailidis','Kjetil Nørvåg']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

[image]

The aim is to create a dataframe with 3 columns. In the 3rd column, I will count how many times each pair appear together in a paper but I don't want the pairs that didn't appear together(the pairs that have weigh equal to 0). I also want if for a paper was only one author, to pair ones its seft from itself to itself weight = 1. The output I want to be like the one below:

```
from_to_weight = {'From':['Dimitrios Rafailidis','Dimitrios Rafailidis','Dimitrios Rafailidis','Dimitrios Rafailidis','Dimitrios Rafailidis','Fabio Crestani','Fabio Crestani','Fabio Crestani','Tomasz Kusmierczyk','Tomasz Kusmierczyk','Tomasz Kusmierczyk','Kjetil Nørvåg','Kjetil Nørvåg','Simranjit Singh Sachar','Simranjit Singh Sachar','Simranjit Singh Sachar','Nicholas Diakopoulos','Nicholas Diakopoulos','Nicholas Diakopoulos','Nicholas Diakopoulos','Nasser Alsaedi', 'Nasser Alsaedi','Pete Burnap', 'Pete Burnap','Omer F. Rana','Omer F. Rana','Omer F. Rana','Omer F. Rana','Omer F. Rana'],
'To':['Fabio Crestani', 'Tomasz Kusmierczyk', 'Simranjit Singh Sachar', 'Nicholas Diakopoulos', 'Omer F. Rana', 'Dimitrios Rafailidis', 'Nicholas Diakopoulos', 'Omer F. Rana','Dimitrios Rafailidis','Kjetil Nørvåg', 'Simranjit Singh Sachar','Tomasz Kusmierczyk', 'Kjetil Nørvåg','Dimitrios Rafailidis','Tomasz Kusmierczyk','Nicholas Diakopoulos','Dimitrios Rafailidis','Fabio Crestani', 'Simranjit Singh Sachar', 'Omer F. Rana','Pete Burnap', 'Omer F. Rana','Nasser Alsaedi', 'Omer F. Rana','Dimitrios Rafailidis', 'Fabio Crestani', 'Nicholas Diakopoulos', 'Nasser Alsaedi', 'Pete Burnap'],
'weight':[2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}

from_to_weight_df = pd.DataFrame(data=from_to_weight)
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check dummified names and matrix multiplication.

```
authors = df["Authors"].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
pairs = authors.T.dot(authors).replace(0, pd.NA).stack()
from_to_weight_df = pairs[pairs.index.get_level_values(0)!=pairs.index.get_level_values(1)].rename_axis(["From", "To"]).reset_index(name="weight")


                      From                      To weight
0     Dimitrios Rafailidis          Fabio Crestani      2
1     Dimitrios Rafailidis    Nicholas Diakopoulos      1
2     Dimitrios Rafailidis            Omer F. Rana      1
3     Dimitrios Rafailidis  Simranjit Singh Sachar      1
4     Dimitrios Rafailidis      Tomasz Kusmierczyk      1
5           Fabio Crestani    Dimitrios Rafailidis      2
6           Fabio Crestani    Nicholas Diakopoulos      1
7           Fabio Crestani            Omer F. Rana      1
8            Kjetil Nørvåg      Tomasz Kusmierczyk      1
9           Nasser Alsaedi            Omer F. Rana      1
10          Nasser Alsaedi             Pete Burnap      1
11    Nicholas Diakopoulos    Dimitrios Rafailidis      1
12    Nicholas Diakopoulos          Fabio Crestani      1
13    Nicholas Diakopoulos            Omer F. Rana      1
14    Nicholas Diakopoulos  Simranjit Singh Sachar      1
15            Omer F. Rana    Dimitrios Rafailidis      1
16            Omer F. Rana          Fabio Crestani      1
17            Omer F. Rana          Nasser Alsaedi      1
18            Omer F. Rana    Nicholas Diakopoulos      1
19            Omer F. Rana             Pete Burnap      1
20             Pete Burnap          Nasser Alsaedi      1
21             Pete Burnap            Omer F. Rana      1
22  Simranjit Singh Sachar    Dimitrios Rafailidis      1
23  Simranjit Singh Sachar    Nicholas Diakopoulos      1
24  Simranjit Singh Sachar      Tomasz Kusmierczyk      1
25      Tomasz Kusmierczyk    Dimitrios Rafailidis      1
26      Tomasz Kusmierczyk           Kjetil Nørvåg      1
27      Tomasz Kusmierczyk  Simranjit Singh Sachar      1
```